# Multi-Threading JaxRs calls - parallelStream or Futures?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, jersey, jax-rs

I'm trying to figure out if it is safe to do a synchronous JaxRs asynchronously through a parallel stream.

Here is a code sample :

```
public class Singleton { // I'm a Singleton

private WebTarget webtarget;

public void deleteElement(String id) {
    try {
        Response res = this.webtarget.path("/item/{id}").request().buildDelete().invoke();
        if (res.getStatusInfo() != Response.Status.OK) {
            throw new TechnicalException("distant service failed and responded" + res.getStatus());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("error");
        throw new TechnicalException("error", e);
    }
  }
}
```

Is it safe to call this code in a parallel stream ? Or is it not and I should use `submit()`instead of `invoke()` to get a `Future<Response>` so I can join after all the deletions.

Comment: Besides the `WebTarget`, which is safe as it creates a new `WebTarget` when you call `path()`, what about this do you think could possibly not be safe?

Comment: My question, beside being threadsafe, is, will it really be treated asynchronously or will the `Webtarget` be locked while the previous `submit` resolves.

Comment: There's no lock. Once you call `webtarget.path()`, you get a new `WebTarget`.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks, that answers my question.